# compare counts of values in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables I would like to highlight if there is a difference in the number of occurances of a value between the two tables. So essentially, Table 1 could contain 4 rows with the word "Ball" in one of the columns and table 2 also contains 4 rows with the word ball in one of  the columns. This would be ignored. But it the word ball had 4 instances in table 1 and 6 in table two I would like the output to be something like:

```
"Column Name"  "Table 1" "Table 2"  
  Ball             4          6
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Whoops should have said! MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
   SELECT ColName,
          COUNT(ColName) AS NameCount
   FROM   Table1
   GROUP BY ColName
),CTE2 AS
(
   SELECT ColName,
          COUNT(ColName) AS NameCount
   FROM   Table2
   GROUP BY ColName
)
SELECT * 
FROM   CTE1 C1
       FULL OUTER JOIN CTE2 C2
       ON C1.ColName = C2.ColName
WHERE  C1.NameCount <> C2.NameCount
```

Comment: I got the impression that the word "ball" was not the only word in the column.  @Liam, can you clarify this?

Comment: This won't work only for `ball`. I create a count for each item in the column for both tables. Then i join them using the column name (balls with balls, rackets with rackets, etc....) and if the counts are different, then i display them.

Comment: Also, `FULL OUTER JOIN` will ensure that i get orphaned rows from both tables.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt clarify.  I meant to say that it sounds like the columns value is something like "how many balls are in the ball pit", not that the query needed to be restricted by the word ball.

Comment: He stated that he wants to count instances of the word `ball` (or any other word, as `ball` is the example) in both tables and check if there are any mismatches. At least, this is my understanding.

Comment: His example seems to support your understanding, this is a fine solution for that.

Comment: The answer given is precisely what I was looking for. I can now compare the differences in occurances in each table.

Comment: Add a comma after `SELECT ColName` in both statements, it took me a minute of confusion when it didn't work.

Comment: @SamWhite thanks, i am usually writting my answers on the fly and my mental parser is not fully debugged yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

This alternative properly handles the cases where a value is in one table but not the other.  The execution plan will be similar to that of a CTE version such as the one in jyparask's answer.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.ColumnName, t2.ColumnName) AS [Column Name],
    COALESCE(t1.Occurrences, 0) AS [Table 1],
    COALESCE(t2.Occurrences, 0) AS [Table 2]
FROM (
    SELECT
        ColumnName,
        COUNT(ColumnName) AS Occurrences
    FROM
        Table1
    GROUP BY
        ColumnName
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ColumnName,
        COUNT(ColumnName) AS Occurrences
    FROM
        Table2
    GROUP BY
        ColumnName
) t2
ON
    t1.ColumnName = t2.ColumnName
WHERE
    COALESCE(t1.Occurrences, 0) <> COALESCE(t2.Occurrences, 0)
```